# How to read data from from web link with drop-down fields using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

I wand to read and data from below link to pandas dataframe using Python.

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm'

It has some drop-down fields like Select Instrument,Select Symbol,Select Year,Select Expiry,Select Option Type,Enter Strike Price, Select a time period etc.

[image: NSE Page]

I want to send the output to pandas dataframe for further processing.

Comment: Use "Network" in DevTool in Chrome/Firefox to see all requests from browser to server. When I click "Get Data" then I see url with options from drop-down fields  like `https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?instrumentType=FUTIDX&symbol=NIFTY&expiryDate=select&optionType=select&strikePrice=&dateRange=day&fromDate=&toDate=&segmentLink=9&symbolCount=` You can try to use this url directly in `pd.read_html("https://...")` to get all tables in html. OR you can try to use modules `requests`/`urllib`+`Beautifulsoup`/`lxml` to get HTML and scrape data from HTML.

Comment: Sir, I am new to web scrape. Can you help me with few lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `"Network"` in `DevTool` in Chrome/Firefox I can see all requests from browser to server. When I click "Get Data" then I see url with options from drop-down fields like

https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?instrumentType=FUTIDX&symbol=NIFTY&expiryDate=select&optionType=select&strikePrice=&dateRange=day&fromDate=&toDate=&segmentLink=9&symbolCount=

Normally I could use url directly in `pd.read_html("https://...")` to get all tables in HTML and later I could use `[0]` to get first table as DataFrame.

Because I get error so I use module `requests` to get HTML and then I use `pd.read_html("string_with_html")` to convert all tables in HTML to DataFrames.

It gives me `DataFrame` with multi-level column index and with 3 unknow columns which I drop.

More information in comments in code

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# create session to get and keep cookies
s = requests.Session()

# get page and cookies 
url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm'
s.get(url)

# get HTML with tables
url = "https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?instrumentType=FUTIDX&symbol=NIFTY&expiryDate=select&optionType=select&strikePrice=&dateRange=day&fromDate=&toDate=&segmentLink=9&symbolCount="
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Referer': 'https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm'
}

# get HTML from url    
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print('status:', r.status_code)
#print(r.text)

# user pandas to parse tables in HTML to DataFrames
all_tables = pd.read_html(r.text)
print('tables:', len(all_tables))


# get first DataFrame
df = all_tables[0]
#print(df.columns)

# drop multilevel column index
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
#print(df.columns)

# droo unknow columns
df = df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 14_level_1', 'Unnamed: 15_level_1', 'Unnamed: 16_level_1'])
print(df.columns)
```

Result

```
Index(['Symbol', 'Date', 'Expiry', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'LTP',
       'Settle Price', 'No. of contracts', 'Turnover * in Lacs', 'Open Int',
       'Change in OI', 'Underlying Value'],
      dtype='object')


  Symbol         Date       Expiry  ...  Open Int  Change in OI  Underlying Value
0  NIFTY  16-May-2019  30-May-2019  ...  15453150       -242775           11257.1
1  NIFTY  16-May-2019  27-Jun-2019  ...   1995975        383250           11257.1
2  NIFTY  16-May-2019  25-Jul-2019  ...    116775          2775           11257.1

[3 rows x 14 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks Sir. I am getting error as "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Comment: when I run now I get error 405 and HTML with message "Access denied". I added session to keep cookies and some headers (see code in answer) and I can get tables but I'm not sure if it works because I use session or because I opened url in web browser and it sent some other information which are needed to correctly get data.

Comment: Sir, how to collect data for a particular range. Getting error with date formats. Any help.

Comment: using `DevTools` I see url with dates ie. `&dateRange=&fromDate=12-May-2019&toDate=19-May-2019` or with range `&dateRange=3month&fromDate=&toDate=` - similar to HTML `<option value="3month">90 Days</option>`

Comment: Ahh, My Bad I was using the date with quotes. Sir, one more thing the output is restricted to max 100 rows. Why any reason..?

Comment: the reason can be money. They may earn on data so you would have to pay for more data. Or they may want to restrict traffic in network. They send less data so computers use less power and they pay less money for computers.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

#############################################
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)
pd.set_option('display.width', 50000)
#############################################

# create session to get and keep cookies
s = requests.Session()

# get page and cookies
url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm'
s.get(url)

# get HTML with tables
symbol = ['SBIN']

dates = ['17-May-2019']

url = "https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?instrumentType=OPTSTK&symbol=" + symbol[0] + "&expiryDate=select&optionType=CE&strikePrice=&dateRange=day&fromDate=" + dates[0] + "&toDate=" + dates[0] + "&segmentLink=9&symbolCount="
# print(url)

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Referer': 'https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm'
}

# get HTML from url
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
# print('status:', r.status_code)
# print(r.text)

# user pandas to parse tables in HTML to DataFrames
all_tables = pd.read_html(r.text)
# print('tables:', len(all_tables))


# get first DataFrame
df = all_tables[0]
# print(df.columns)

df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[1]).drop(df.index[0])
df = df.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)

df = df[['Symbol','Date','Expiry','Optiontype','Strike Price','Close','LTP','No. of contracts','Open Int','Change in OI','Underlying Value']]
print(df)
```